# Wordpress : Php Break after function?

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, parent-child

So I have this to echo only the parents- child links :

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<ul class="nav nav-list submenu">

<?
    $child_pages = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_parent = ".$post->ID." AND post_type = 'page' ORDER BY menu_order", 'OBJECT');
    if ( $child_pages ) :
    foreach ( $child_pages as $pageChild ) :
    setup_postdata( $pageChild );
?>

<a href="<?= get_permalink($pageChild->ID) ?>" rel="bookmark">
<li class="subnav"><?= $pageChild->post_title?>     </li>
</a>

<?
    endforeach;
    endif;
?> 
</ul></div>
```

Then here is where the problem lyes. So.

I have this to echo the pages content

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

And its echoing the last childs content to the content area.
How can I do this so, that I can get the links, and get the content where is should go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_content` is a function that assumes there's a global `$post` variable set to whatever you need. By default wordpress instantiates it with the content of the current page/post.

`setup_postdata` overwrites that global `$post` variable so that your next call to `get_permalink` automatically refers to `$pageChild`. But now `the_content` does the same thing, so you need to somehow reset `$post` to whatever value it had before you called `setup_postdata`.

Lucky for you, there's a [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) called `wp_reset_postdata` that you need to call that does exactly that so `the_content`'s output is correct (refers to the original `$post`).